# How to display a ManyToMany fields in the template

Tags: python, django, templates, many-to-many

I wonder how I can retrieve my template a ManyToMany fields ...
For example, in my model I would like to retrieve the page corresponding to each question and post it in the template ...
I have 4 values in my class Page ("visit 1 visit 2 visit 3, 4 .. visit")
And I associated in my database each question with a "visit"

And I wish I could now see how visits to any question in my template.

I will share my models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 20, 15, 4, 21, 467165))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

And my templates :

```
{% for reply in replies %}<br>
    <br> {{ reply.user }}
    {{ reply.question }} -
    {{ reply.answer }}
    (dans la :{% for page in questions.page %} {{ page }}) {% endfor %}  #this is this line who doesn't work 
{% endfor %}
```

**How do I call in the template page for a given question?**

> EDIT :

```
def reply(request):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    form = ReplyBisForm(request.GET)
    personnes = Personne.objects.all()
    if logged_user:
        if len(request.GET) > 0:
            form = ReplyBisForm(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/reply')
            else:
                return render_to_response('polls/reply.html', {'personnes': personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions,'pages':pages, 'form': form})
        else:
            form = ReplyBisForm()
            return render_to_response('polls/reply.html', {'personnes':personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions, 'pages':pages, 'form': form})
    else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

Comment: why are you trying to do the for block inside the first for block of replies?

Comment: @AhmedHosny because I want it to make a loop to display each question for each question then a loop to display EVERY pages corresponding to each question

Comment: If you're iterating through replies in the database, your questions and pages variables in this view are irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why isn't irrelevant ?

Comment: Because you access the related questions and pages through the reply, as Alex has shown you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman And how do I view the pages linked by the questions?

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can I view the pages related to each of my questions? What do I call?

Comment: You do what Alex said. He has the exact correct answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's work ! thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102981/discussion-between-jeremy-lgdr-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a `ManyToMany` field is transformed to a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) for every model instance, you should specify a subset of your related objects, or just go with [`all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#all):

```
(dans la :{% for page in reply.question.page.all %} {{ page }}) {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This reply does'nt work for me :s I can share my views

Comment: Well, it should. Check if your `question` has actual `pages` in the database.

Comment: Now, it's work for me don't understand what I did before ! Thanks you

Comment: Glad you've sorted it out.

Comment: Can I contact you by email for another question in the same style ?

Comment: Jeremy, I guess the best option is to ask another question here on SO, so that I won't be the only person who can help you.